# A message received by adapter "HTTP" on receive location "Receive_AS2" with URI "/Contoso/BTSHTTPReceive.dll" is suspended

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, edi

I'm developing a demo of EDI over AS2 with asynchronous MDN but receiving this error upon executing Sender.exe, this error is shown in Event Viewer...

> A message received by adapter "HTTP" on receive location "Receive_AS2" with URI "/Contoso/BTSHTTPReceive.dll" is suspended. 
>    Error details: The output message of the receive pipeline "Microsoft.BizTalk.EdiInt.DefaultPipelines.AS2EdiReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.EdiIntPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" failed routing because there is no subscribing orchestration or send port.
>
> The sequence number of the suspended message is 3.
>
> MessageId:  {D81813E2-9057-41CD-8A44-1528AEF85476}
>
> InstanceID: {2B08DCAF-3D26-4BFC-AB04-8282891AA399}

I don't know what is going wrong , I followed MSDN tutorial line to line but its not executing right....

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben, the line '...failed routing because there is no subscribing orchestration or send port' is the key one here. You need to have either a Send Port or Orchestration subscribing (i.e. listening) for messages that are received.

Not knowing your specific application, I would suggest that you either don't have a subscribing Send Port or Orchestration, or they are not started.

[This MSDN Forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/biztalkediandas2/thread/45835d2c-d325-4446-b129-dfa5df261492) might help as well.