# failed routing due to no subscribing orchestration or send port

Tags: biztalk, edi

I am really stuck at the message below and tried solving it but couldn't find the exact solution. The same invoice goes smoothly when I put in a different supplier folder, but when I put this in newly created supplier, it shows this. I tried creating the same ports and receive_location the other supplier had.

> {5ACBE71C-0568-4C09-9F8C-EF9286FD174F} 
>   {08A1620B-8888-4899-843E-AA403A64BCDA} 
>   FILE 
>   C:\Integration Location\EDI\IN\Turi*.edi 
>    Receive Location_Turi_Invoices 
>      The output message of the receive pipeline "Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.DefaultPipelines.EdiReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.EdiPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" failed routing because there is no subscribing orchestration or send port. The sequence number of the suspended message is 1.
>   Could you guys please help with this?

Comment: What you need to do is look at the promoted properties on the suspended message and compare that to the subscription on the send port or Orchestration you expect to handle the message.   If you still can't see the problem, post details of those to the question.  Otherwise nobody can help you.  Note: The Orchestration / Send port need to be Enlisted or Started for their subscription to be published

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A message received by adapter "HTTP" on receive location "Receive\_AS2" with URI "/Contoso/BTSHTTPReceive.dll" is suspended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100127/a-message-received-by-adapter-http-on-receive-location-receive-as2-with-uri)